# For Lyx, and beamer how do I generate the red bracket on the left as attached

Tags: beamer, lyx

For LyX and `beamer`. how do I generate a "new" red bracket on the very left of the attached picture? I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: tab should work. Which version of LyX are you using? Do you know about Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations? It is full of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. This is what "nests" the environment in the parent environment in LyX. The rectangles give an indication of how deep the nesting is.

Note also that <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> (on Linux at least, not sure if different on other OS) does the opposite---it reduces the nesting level by one.